# Kendo mvc grid with multiselect column SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'set' of undefined or null reference

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-multiselect

At first I want to apologize for my bad english.
And so, I have two models with relationship "Many to Many", Books, Authors, and their context Library. All source files included correctly, have no idea why my code doesn't work.

My problem was described in title. I hope for your help).
All code is below(you don't have to read all code, i think problem in my javascript, because my javascript skill is pretty bad).
An error occurs when I try to set selected authors in a row
[in this moment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PVro.jpg)

**Problem in Index.cshtml file here:**(in change function)

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    function dataBound(e) {
        var grid = this;
        grid.tbody.children().each(function () {
            var dataitem = grid.dataItem(this),
                row = $(this);
            eval(row.find("script").html());
            var multiSelect = $(this).find("select").data("kendoMultiSelect");
            multiSelect.value(dataitem.Authors.map(function (i) { return i.AuthorId }));
        });
    }

    function change(e) {
        var row = this.element.closest("tr"),
            **//problem is here**
            model = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataItem(row);
        model.set("Authors", this.dataItems());
    }
    function error_handler(e) {
        if (e.errors) {
            var message = "Errors:\n";
            $.each(e.errors, function (key, value) {
                if ('errors' in value) {
                    $.each(value.errors, function () {
                        message += this + "\n";
                    });
                }
            });
            alert(message);
        }
    }
</script>
```

```html
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ManyToMany.Models.ViewModel>()
                .Name("grid")
                .Columns(columns =>
                {
                    columns.Bound(e => e.BookId).Visible(false);
                    columns.Bound(e => e.Pages);
                    columns.Bound(e => e.Genre);
                    columns.Bound(e => e.Publisher);
                    columns.Bound(e => e.Authors).ClientTemplate(

                         Html.Kendo().MultiSelect().Name("multi#=BookId#")
                            .DataTextField("AuthorName")
                            .DataValueField("AuthorId")
                            .BindTo((IEnumerable<ManyToMany.Models.Author>)ViewData["authors"]) /*TaskSecond.Models.ViewModel*/
                            .Events(e => e.Change("change"))
                            .ToClientTemplate().ToHtmlString()
                        );
                    columns.Command(command => command.Destroy()).Width(150);

                })
                .ToolBar(toolbar =>
                {
                    toolbar.Create();
                    toolbar.Save();
                })
                .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
                                                    .Pageable()
                                                    .Filterable()
                .Events(e => e.DataBound("dataBound"))
                .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                    .Ajax()
                    .Batch(true)
                .Model(model =>
                {
                    model.Id(p => p.BookId);
                    model.Field(p => p.Pages).DefaultValue(0);
                    model.Field(p => p.Genre).DefaultValue(0);
                    model.Field(p => p.Publisher).DefaultValue("");
                    model.Field(p => p.Authors).DefaultValue(
                        ViewData["defaultAuthors"] as ManyToMany.Models.Author);
                })
                    .PageSize(5)
                     .Read(read => read.Action("Books_Read", "Grid"))
        .Create(create => create.Action("Books_Create", "Grid"))
         .Update(update => update.Action("Books_Update", "Grid"))
        .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Books_Destroy", "Grid"))
                    .ServerOperation(false))
)
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//defaultAuthors.cshtml
@model IEnumerable<ManyToMany.Models.ViewModel>

@(
                Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(m => m)
                    .DataTextField("AuthorName")
                    .DataValueField("AuthorId")
                    .BindTo((IEnumerable<ManyToMany.Models.ViewModel>)ViewData["authors"])
)
```

**My Controller:**

```
public class GridController : Controller
```

{
        private Library db = new Library();

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var temp = db.Authors.FirstOrDefault();
        List<Author> author = new List<Author>();
        author.Add(temp);
        ViewData["defaultAuthors"] = author;
        ViewData["authors"] = db.Authors;            
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Books_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        IQueryable<Book> books = db.Books;
        DataSourceResult result = books.ToDataSourceResult(request, c => new ViewModel
        {
            BookId = c.BookId,
            BookName = c.BookName,
            Pages = c.Pages,
            Genre = c.Genre,
            Publisher = c.Publisher,
            Authors = new List<Author>(c.Authors)
        });

        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Books_Create([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, [Bind(Prefix = "models")]IEnumerable<ViewModel> books)
    {
        var entities = new List<Book>();
        if (books != null && ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            foreach (var book in books)
            {
                var entity = new Book
                {
                    BookName = book.BookName,
                    Pages = book.Pages,
                    Genre = book.Genre,
                    Publisher = book.Publisher,
                    Authors = new List<Author>(book.Authors)
                };

                db.Books.Add(entity);
                entities.Add(entity);
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        return Json(entities.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState, book => new ViewModel
        {
            BookName = book.BookName,
            Pages = book.Pages,
            Genre = book.Genre,
            Publisher = book.Publisher,
            Authors = new List<Author>(book.Authors)
        }));
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Books_Update([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, [Bind(Prefix = "models")]IEnumerable<ViewModel> books)
    {

        var entities = new List<Book>();
        if (books != null && ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            foreach (var book in books)
            {
                var entity = new Book
                {
                    BookId = book.BookId,
                    BookName = book.BookName,
                    Pages = book.Pages,
                    Genre = book.Genre,
                    Publisher = book.Publisher,
                    Authors = new List<Author>(book.Authors)
                };

                entities.Add(entity);
                db.Books.Attach(entity);
                db.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
            db.SaveChanges();

        }

        return Json(entities.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState, book => new ViewModel
        {
            BookName = book.BookName,
            Pages = book.Pages,
            Genre = book.Genre,
            Publisher = book.Publisher,
            Authors = new List<Author>(book.Authors)
        }));
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Books_Destroy([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, [Bind(Prefix = "models")]IEnumerable<ViewModel> books)
    {
        var entities = new List<Book>();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            foreach (var book in books)
            {
                var entity = new Book
                {
                    BookId = book.BookId,
                    BookName = book.BookName,
                    Pages = book.Pages,
                    Genre = book.Genre,
                    Publisher = book.Publisher,
                    Authors = new List<Author>(book.Authors)
                };

                entities.Add(entity);
                db.Books.Attach(entity);
                db.Books.Remove(entity);
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        return Json(entities.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState, book => new ViewModel
        {
            BookName = book.BookName,
            Pages = book.Pages,
            Genre = book.Genre,
            Publisher = book.Publisher,
            Authors = new List<Author>(book.Authors)
        }));
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

**Models:**

```
using System.Data.Entity;

public class Library : DbContext
{

    public Library()
       : base("name=Library")
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Author> Authors { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

    }
}
```

}

```
public class Book
{
    public Book()
    {

    }
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int BookId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Book Name")]
    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Book Name must be 100 characters or less"), MinLength(5)]
    public string BookName { get; set; }
    public int Pages { get; set; }

    public string Publisher { get; set; }

    public Genre Genre { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<Author> Authors { get; set; }
}
public class Author
{
    public Author()
    {

    }
    [Required]
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Author Name")]
    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Author Name must be 100 characters or less"), MinLength(5)]
    public string AuthorName { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
```

**MyViewModel**

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Authors = new List<Author>();
    }
    public int BookId { get; set; }

    public string BookName { get; set; }

    public int Pages { get; set; }

    public Genre Genre { get; set; }

    public string Publisher { get; set; }

    [UIHint("AuthorsEditor")]
    public List<Author> Authors { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is _all_ this code strictly relevant to your issue? There's too much to read. Try and create an https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Does row have a value in the change event?

Comment: No, it doesn't. And i dunno why.

Comment: Console say that the value is null or undefined

Comment: The question is still relevant